# Counterexample: If $f^{-1}(B) \subset A$, then $B \subset f(A)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y,A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$. If $f^{-1}(B) \subset A$, then $B \subset f(A)$

I cannot understand that why this statement is false.
Any counterexample?

Comment: What is the role of set $B$ here?

Comment: this is question given in test. I have no idea for that $B$

Comment: I suspect that $B$ and $E$ are notations for the same set. It is probably by accident that different letters have been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As counterexample let $A=X$ and $B=Y$. We always have $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ but $Y\subset f(X)$ is only true if $f$ is surjective which does not have to be the case.